# An array where every element is a divisor of a number and the divisor of the next one

Tags: c++, arrays

Before anything, I am a newbie in programming. I am actually a high school student, so therefore my question may sound stupid.
I want to create an array where every element is a divisor of a number and the divisor of the next one: e.g. for n=12

```
1 2 6 12
```

My solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, d, i, j, a[100];
    cin>>n;
    for(d=n; d>=1; d--)
    {
        if(n%d==0)
            j++;
    }

    for(i=1; i<=j; i++)
    {
        for(d=n; d>=1; d--)
        {
            if(n%d==0)
                a[i]=n%d;
        }
    }
    for(i=1; i<=j; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[1];
        if(a[i]%a[i+1]==0)
            cout<<a[i+1]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following error:-1073741676 (0xC0000094)

A solution to this problem would be much appreciated. I am new to this community and I have really become passionate about programming since I entered high school. Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you will have to extract a [mcve] from your code and be more precise about what you actually observed. Without an in-depth analysis, check for buffer overflows and use of uninitialized values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Set a breakpoint at if(a[i]%a[i+1]==0) and examine the value of i. It will exceed the size of your array.

Comment: Welcome to both Stack Overflow and programming in general!  One question (and possible followup) Are you getting a compile or runtime error?

Comment: array indices are 0 based, ie valid indices into `a[100]` are 0 till 99 not 1 till 100

Comment: Yesterday I only indicated the problems in your proposal, today I edited my answer to give two ways to do, each giving a different result

Answer (score 1):

*j* is used including to compute an index in *a*, but it is never initialized in your *main*

In

```
if(a[i]%a[i+1]==0)
```

You initialize *a* doing `if(n%d==0) a[i]=n%d;` so `a[i+1]` is always 0 so the modulo is always invalid.

Furthermore, because you initialize only *a* up to the index *j* you access to an uninitialized value doing `a[i+1]` when *i* is *j*

---

A possibility is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;

  if (!(cin >> n))
    return -1;

  if (n == 0) {
    cout << "there are an infinite number of solution for 0" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  vector<int> v;

  // 1 is a first value
  v.push_back(1);

  int max = (n > 0) ? n : -n;

  for (int d = 2; d <= max; ++d) {
    if ((n % d) == 0) {
      // can be a candidate, check if compatible with last value
      if ((d % v.back()) == 0)
        v.push_back(d);
    }
  }

  for (vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

We are in C++, so I use a *vector* rather than a C array with a max size

I check a number was read, and I bypass the case of 0, I also manages the case where the input number is negative to stop the search, and I decide to use positive values.

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra v.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12
1 2 4 12 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Note that if I search from the number rather than from 1 that gives other values :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;

  if (!(cin >> n))
    return -1;

  if (n == 0) {
    cout << "there are an infinite number of solution for 0" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  list<int> v;

  // the number itself is a first value
  v.push_back(n);

  for (int d = ((n > 0) ? n : -n) - 1; d != 0; --d) {
    if ((n % d) == 0) {
      // can be a candidate, check if compatible with first value
      if ((v.front() % d) == 0)
        v.push_front(d);
    }
  }

  for (list<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << ' ';
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

That time I use a *list* to `push_front`, it was possible to still use a *vector* putting the value in the reverse order compared to the first version

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra vv.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
12
1 3 6 12
```